# looking for similar known problems

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, proof

I am trying to prove the computer complexity of this optimization problem:
Given a connected graph G = (V, E) and a set S ⊊ V. Find a connected subgraph G'= (V', E ') that:

```
Min f(G')
Min |V'|
```

subjet to:

```
S ⊊ V’
V’ ⊆ V
```

It looks like a generalization of the minimum spanning tree problem when not all vertexes have to be included in the tree. 
Is there a known problem that can be used to proof the complexity of this problem by reduction?

Comment: Actually, it's more like a generalization of MST than a special case. Are there any constraints on f?

Comment: There are no constraints over f. Suppose f is a function that sums the degree of every vertex in G'

Comment: You are right larsmans, it's a generalization of the MSP problem. I'll edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for an interesting question, but I can't offer any real help :)

Comment: It might not be general enough but maybe take a look at [Steiner trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree), in which you want to find the optimal way to connect a predefined set of vertices in a larger graph. It's an old NP hard problem so you might be able to reduce it to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem formulation is not saying what you're optimizing on-- f(G') first and within that Min|V'|, or the other way round, or the two combined in some way.

if you optimize on the cost edges, it is the Steiner minimal tree (SMT) problem as is and NP-complete. if you optimize on |V'|, you can reduce SMT to it in polynomial time with the following:

Let edge (u,v) between nodes u and v have cost k. Replace this edge by the following path:

```
(u, i_1), (i_1, i_2), ..., (i_k, v)
```

so that the cost of each edge on this path is 1. You replaced the edge of cost (u, v) with a path with k-1 intermediary nodes on it and every edge has cost 1.

Do this for every edge on graph. It reduces SMT to your problem and proves that yours optimizing on |V'| is NP-complete. Your reduction takes

```
O(C*|V|^2)
```

time where C is an upper bound on the cost of edges in graph.

Just saw the problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi ashley, thanks for your answer! According my problem restrictions I can't use vertices in G' which are not in G (V’ ⊆ V); so I am confused about your proof using Steiner Minimal Tree problem (SMT uses Steiner points). 
About the optimizations functions, you are right, they are not clear enough; I'll edit the question.

Comment: (1/2) I assume you are referring to the nodes added during the reduction. 
This would't violate your condition: Suppose your SMT problem 
to reduce is on graph H=(V_h, E_h) where the edges of H are weighted. 
Suppose that N is the set of nodes that are required be on SMT to be 
constructed on H where N is a subset of V_h. Through the polynomial 
reduction, you converted this graph into H_2=(V_2, E_2). Clearly, V_2 is 
a superset of V_h which in turn is a superset of V_h
and the weight of each edge in E_2 is 1.

Comment: (2/2) V_2 is the graph you would be feeding into the algorithm 
to solve your problem-- the input in this case is the graph H_2 and the set N. 
The nodes on the solution that the algorithm to solve your problem, which is the solution
to SMT are all on the input graph which is H_2. There is no violation of the condition you are referring to. 
Your algorithm isn't adding or assuming anything to the input graph. It's merely processing on it.

Comment: umm, you are right. Graph H2 is the reduction function result.